# how to properly implement attributeHasFieldErrors ( without 'AssertionError: No BindingResult for attribute: abc' error )

Tags: junit, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am trying to use `.andExpect(model().attributeHasFieldErrors` in my unit test.

According to [this page](http://www.waitingforcode.com/spring-framework/spring-integration-testing-for-controllers/read) java.lang.AssertionError: No BindingResult for attribute: abc is caused because the view returned by tested controller is a redirect: "redirect:/xyz/add".

But at the same time, most of `@PostMapping(/...)` use redirect. Does it mean that in this kind of cases there is no way of knowing if `attributeHasFieldErrors` ?

It seems to be possible - in this [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/owner/OwnerControllerTests.java) it seems to be working - BUT I am confused on this:

There `testProcessUpdateOwnerFormHasErrors` test-method (*second method from bottom in above link*) performs POST `[ i.e. mockMvc.perform(post(... ]` , and expects view name that is returned by GET method in Controller class.

That is, `@GetMapping("/owners/{ownerId}/edit")` returns `"owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm"` and `@PostMapping("/owners/{ownerId}/edit")` returns `"redirect:/owners/{ownerId}"` in Controller. And above test performing POST expects `"owners/createOrUpdateOwnerForm"`. Should it not expect `"redirect:/owners/{ownerId}"` ?

I am confused.

Can someone explain proper way of implementing `attributeHasFieldErrors`?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you use redirect when there are no errors, to avoid multiple POSTS. When 
there is an error, the normal way to proceed would be to redisplay the same view with the error messages.

Something like :

```java
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String processForm(@Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        if ( ! bindingResult.hasErrors()) {         
            Long id = service.saveUser(userForm.getUser()); 
            return "redirect:/user/"+id;
        } else {
          return "calcForm";
        }
    }
```